# PHP PDO transaction Duplicating

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a game website and I want to update the users money, however if I use 2 pc's at the exact same time this code will execute twice and the user will be left with minus money. How can I stop this from happening? It's driving me crazy.

```
$db = getDB();  
$sql = "UPDATE users SET money = money- :money WHERE username=:user";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);                                  
$stmt->bindParam(':money', $amount, PDO::PARAM_STR);       
$stmt->bindParam(':user', $user, PDO::PARAM_STR);       
$stmt->execute();
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The problem you've got here is determining whether the transaction is a genuine second transaction (if the user wants to buy an item twice), or whether it's accidental. If you're using 2 PC's there's not a great deal you can do about this problem, you can resolve this being an issue for genuine users who will usually just be using one machine by disabling the input on the first click. If you want to stop users from "conning the system" but over buying, you'll need to make all transactions for a user into a "queue" and process them individually with feedback if the user has insufficient funds.

Comment: A good solution to the 2 PC problem would be to only allow sessions from one device at a time, logging them out from their other sessions should they log in from another device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Echoing the comment from @GarryWelding: the database update isn't an appropriate place in the code to handle the use case that is described.  Locking a row in the user table isn't the right fix.

Back up a step.  It sounds like we are wanting some fine grained control over user purchases. Seems like we need a place to store a record of user purchases, and then we can can check that.

Without diving into a database design, I'm going to throw out some ideas here...

In addition to the "user" entity

```
user
   username
   account_balance
```

Seems like we are interested in some information about purchases a user has made. I'm throwing out some ideas about the information/attributes that might be of interest to us, not making any claim that these are all needed for your use case:

```
user_purchase
   username that made the purchase
   items/services purchased
   datetime the purchase was originated
   money_amount of the purchase
   computer/session the purchase was made from
   status (completed, rejected, ...)
   reason (e.g. purchase is rejected, "insufficient funds", "duplicate item"
```

We don't want to try to track all of that information in the "account balance" of a user, especially since there can be multiple purchases from a user.

---

If our use case is much simpler than that, and we only to keep track of the most recent purchase by a user, then we could record that in the user entity.

```
user
  username 
  account_balance ("money")
  most_recent_purchase
     _datetime
     _item_service
     _amount ("money")
     _from_computer/session
```

And then with each purchase, we could record the new account_balance, and overwrite the previous "most recent purchase" information

If all we care about is preventing multiple purchases "at the same time", we need to define that... does that mean within the same exact microsecond? within  10 milliseconds?

Do we only want to prevent "duplicate" purchases from different computers/sessions? What about two duplicate requests on the same session?

---

This is *not* how I would solve the problem. But to answer the question you asked, if we go with a simple use case - "prevent two purchases within a millisecond of each other", and we want to do this in an `UPDATE` of `user` table

Given a table definition like this:

```
user
  username                 datatype    NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY 
  account_balance          datatype    NOT NULL
  most_recent_purchase_dt  DATETIME(6) NOT NULL COMMENT 'most recent purchase dt)
```

with the datetime (down to the microsecond) of the most recent purchase recorded in the user table (using the time returned by the database)

```
UPDATE user u
   SET u.most_recent_purchase_dt = NOW(6) 
     , u.account_balance  = u.account_balance - :money1
 WHERE u.username         = :user
   AND u.account_balance >= :money2
   AND NOT ( u.most_recent_purchase_dt >= NOW(6) + INTERVAL -1000 MICROSECOND
         AND u.most_recent_purchase_dt <  NOW(6) + INTERVAL +1001 MICROSECOND 
           )
```

We can then detect the number of rows affected by the statement.

If we get zero rows affected, then either `:user` wasn't found, or `:money2` was greater than the account balance, or `most_recent_purchase_dt` was within a range of +/- 1 millisecond of now. We can't tell which.

If more than zero rows are affected, then we know that an update occurred.

**EDIT**

To emphasize some key points which might have been overlooked...

The example SQL is expecting support for fractional seconds, which requires MySQL 5.7 or later. In 5.6 and earlier, DATETIME resolution was only down to the second. (Note column definition in the example table and SQL specifies resolution down to microsecond... `DATETIME(6)` and `NOW(6)`.

The example SQL statement is expecting `username` to be the PRIMARY KEY or a UNIQUE key in the `user` table. This is noted (but not highlighted) in the example table definition.

The example SQL statement overrides update of `user` for two statements executed within *one millisecond* of each other. For testing, change that millisecond resolution to a longer interval. for example, change it to one minute.

That is, change the two occurrences of `1000 MICROSECOND` to `60 SECOND`.

A few other notes: use `bindValue` in place of `bindParam` (since we're providing values to the statement, not returning values from the statement.

Also make sure PDO is set to throw an exception when an error occurs (if we aren't going to check the return from the PDO functions in the code) so the code isn't putting it's (figurative) pinky finger to the corner of our mouth Dr.Evil style "I just assume it will all go to plan. What?")

```
# enable PDO exceptions
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$sql = "
UPDATE user u
   SET u.most_recent_purchase_dt = NOW(6) 
     , u.account_balance  = u.account_balance - :money1
 WHERE u.username         = :user
   AND u.account_balance >= :money2
   AND NOT ( u.most_recent_purchase_dt >= NOW(6) + INTERVAL -60 SECOND
         AND u.most_recent_purchase_dt <  NOW(6) + INTERVAL +60 SECOND
           )";

$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql)
$sth->bindValue(':money1', $amount, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->bindValue(':money2', $amount, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->bindValue(':user', $user, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->execute(); 

# check if row was updated, and take appropriate action
$nrows = $sth->rowCount();
if( $nrows > 0 ) {
   // row was updated, purchase successful
} else {
   // row was not updated, purchase unsuccessful
}
```

---

And to emphasize a point I made earlier, "lock the row" is not the right approach to solving the problem. And doing the check the way I demonstrated in the example, doesn't tell us the reason the purchase was unsuccessful (insufficient funds or within specified timeframe of preceding purchase.)

Comment: Hi, I tried your code and I was still able to dupe the transaction twice, I made another transaction table to see the times and both are the exact same time. I'm really lost on how to fix this

Comment: @Chris,  the example SQL should have prevented an UPDATE of user within the same *millisecond*. For testing, I'd broaden that time range to a minute... change the two occurrences of `1000 MICROSECOND` to `60 SECOND`. Also, as indicated in my answer, the code will need to check the number of affected rows `->rowCount()`, to determine if a row is updated or not. (An UPDATE statement that affects zero rows is considered "success"; we would need to check whether a row was updated.)

Comment: Its works now thank you very much, really appreciated :D

Answer (score 0):

for the negative balance change your code to

```
$sql = "UPDATE users SET money = money- :money WHERE username=:user AND money >= :money";
```

Comment: That works for the negative balance but the transaction still gets posted twice

Comment: its there a problem with posting twice, if the user click 2 times on a button then he wants to buy twice, why prevent him from buying?

Comment: if you want to prevent the user from buying a item twice then you need a table to store what he has buyed,and check in that table if he has both that item or not

Answer (score 0):

**First idea:**

If you're using InnoDB, you can use transactions to provide fine-grained mutual exclusion. Example:

```
START TRANSACTION;
UPDATE users SET money = money- :money WHERE username=:user;
COMMIT;
```

If you're using MyISAM, you can use LOCK TABLE to prevent B from accessing the table until A finishes making its changes. Example:

```
LOCK TABLE t WRITE;
UPDATE users SET money = money- :money WHERE username=:user;
```

**Second idea:**

If update don't work, you may delete and insert new row (if you have auto increment id, there won't be duplicates).

Comment: Would I have it set like this? Sorry im not the best in php 

$stmt = "START TRANSACTION";
$sql = "UPDATE users SET money = money- :money WHERE username=:user";
$stmt = "COMMIT;";

Comment: Here's an example that can help you: http://thisinterestsme.com/php-pdo-transaction-example/